# Colour cell background if another cell in same row is empty

Tags: colors, google-sheets, cell, gs-conditional-formatting

I have two columns: In the first there might or might not be a value;
in the second column, if the first cell next to it is empty, I want to colour the cell in a grey colour.

Is there an easy way to change a cells background colour, if a different cell is empty?

Comment: Just use [Conditional Formating](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Please select your second column and with Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if..., **Custom formula is** enter:

```
=isblank(A1)
```

and for Formatting style choose grey fill, <kbd>Done</kbd>.

Change "A" in the formula to the reference letter for your first column.

Comment: Awesome, cheers dude, much appreciated,To get to work for my range, so it didnt include the headers I put: =isblank(G4:G)